# How to remove duplicate number within a list and then replace with a new random number

Tags: python, loops, random, numbers, generator

new to python. I'm trying to make a lottery-styled thing, where the for loop appends `5` random numbers into a list.

Let's say the list so far is `nList = [1,2,3,4]` and the last iteration happens to also be a `4`.

I want the code to remove the extra `4` that was supposed to be in the last index, and replace it with a brand new random number that does NOT duplicate any of the rest of the numbers on the list. I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

I've tried using `nList.pop()`, and that solves the problem of removing the duplicate, I just don't know how to add the new random number.

```
import random
nList = []
random.seed()
for x in range(5):
    n = random.randint(1,39)
    for item in nList:
       if n == item:
            nList.pop()
    else:
        nList.append(n)

print(nList)
```

I just end up with a smaller list, which is not what I want.

Comment: If `n` was already in the list it is removed and newly appended. This means that no new item is added in this loop iteration. Solution: Replace outer for-loop by a while loop testing for the length of `nList`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using a `list` you can use a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) which has the special property of having *no duplicates*. The idea is that if you generate a number that is already inside the `set`, you simply reroll until you get a number that is not in the `set`. By using a set, you also have the advantage of having `O(1)` lookup time.

```
import random

nList = set()
for x in range(5):
    n = random.randint(1,39)
    while n in nList:
        n = random.randint(1,39)
    nList.add(n)

print(list(nList))
```

Example Output

> [24, 25, 11, 12, 15]

Comment: Nice answer and explanations. +1! There exists however a shortcut: `import random
print(random.sample(range(1,39),5))`

Comment: Very interesting, didn't know the `random` module had a built in function to do that

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it in a way easier way, using directly do this from `random` module (*No need to go the hard way and reinvent the wheel - except for learning purpose*):

```
import random
print(random.sample(range(1,39),5))
```

**Example of output:**

```
[29, 20, 26, 17, 37]
```

**Explanations:**

- [`range(1,39)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) to generate the range you need (i.e. your initial population)
- [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) Return a k length list of unique elements chosen from the population sequence.